# Grab first Saturday of each month using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a list of the date of the first saturday each month.
Ideally I'd like it to show the next 6 dates.

I'm thinking of something like

```
function getSaturday($y, $m)
{
    return new DatePeriod(
        new DateTime("first saturday of $y-$m"),
        DateInterval::createFromDateString('next saturday')
    );
}
```

usage

```
foreach (getSaturday(2023, 11) as $saturday) {
    echo $saturday->format("l, Y-m-d\n");
}
```

however this is code I have found and it currently just shows all the Saturdays in the next month. Can anyone help me out with the required changes please?

Comment: Your code actually is show errors. It is not showing all Saturdays as you said. _Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: DatePeriod::__construct() accepts (DateTimeInterface, DateInterval, int [, int]), or (DateTimeInterface, DateInterval, DateTime [, int]), or (string [, int]) as arguments_

Comment: please don't change the question completely, specially when you got a good answer. Reverted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do with a simple loop.

```
const firstSaturday = 'first saturday of next month';
$months = [];
$month = new DateTime(firstSaturday);
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $months[] = $month->format('Y-m-d');
    $month->modify(firstSaturday);
}
print_r($months);
```

### Output

```
2022-12-03
2023-01-07
2023-02-04
2023-03-04
2023-04-01
2023-05-06
```

Comment: Hey,

I added your code above but I'm getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "const" in"

`<?php
const firstSaturday = 'first saturday of next month';
$months = [];
$month = new DateTime(firstSaturday);
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $months[] = $month->format('jS M y');
    $month->modify(firstSaturday);
}
print_r($months); 
echo ' - 10:30am';
?>
`
@markus-zeller

Comment: My code is for PHP 8.1. You can use a variable instead of const, so use `$firstSaturday = 'first saturday of next month';` instead and replace `firstSaturday` with `$firstSaturday`.

Comment: Hi @markus - Is there a way to get it to ignore the first one, for example, I'm looking to remove `2022-12-03` and just show 
`2023-01-07
2023-02-04
2023-03-04
2023-04-01
2023-05-06`

I tried `for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {` but it still shows all the dates?

Comment: Why don't you start from then? `$month = new DateTime('first saturday of 2023-01');`